# "Required Content-Range response header is missing or malformed" while using download_blob in azure blob storage using cdn hostname

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

I have a storage account in azure with a connection string in the format :

```
connection_string = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<storage_account_name>;AccountKey=<redacted_account_key>;EndpointSuffix=azureedge.net'
```

I am trying to download a blob from a container using the cdn hostname `https://<redacted_hostname>.azureedge.net` instead of the origin hostname namely `https://<redacted_hostname_2>.blob.core.windows.net`

I am trying to download and store a blob present in the following way :

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, generate_container_sas , ContainerSasPermissions
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

# get container details
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("container_name")

# get permission
perm = ContainerSasPermissions(read=True,list=True)

# set expiry
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)

# generate sas token
sas_token = generate_container_sas(
       container_client.account_name,
       container_client.container_name,
       account_key=container_client.credential.account_key,
       permission = perm,
       expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)
   )

sas_url = f"https://<redacted_hostname>.azureedge.net/container_name?{sas_token}"
container_with_blob = "container_name/file.wav"
sas_url_parts = urlparse(sas_url)
account_endpoint = sas_url_parts.scheme + '://' + sas_url_parts.netloc
sas_token = sas_url_parts.query
blob_sas_url = account_endpoint + '/' + container_with_blob + '?' + sas_token;
blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url(blob_sas_url);
with open("download_file.wav", "wb") as current_blob:
    stream = blob_client.download_blob()
    current_blob.write(stream.readall())
```

However , this fails with the following error

```
raise ValueError("Required Content-Range response header is missing or malformed.")
ValueError: Required Content-Range response header is missing or malformed
```

however, same snippet works with the `.blob.core.windows.net` hostname

**Attempts to solve issue**

1. Changed `EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net` to `EndpointSuffix=azureedge.net` in `connection_string`.
2. Got the `blob_properties` from `blob_client` and sent it to `download_blob` API as shown below

```
...
blob_properties = blob_client.get_blob_properties()
...
    stream = blob_client.download_blob(0, blob_properties.size)
```

This throws the same error if I am using cdn hostname but works fine using the origin.

3. Tried using `BlobEndpoint=azureedge.net` instead of `EndpointSuffix` .
4. Trying to `set_http_headers` in `blob_client` [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python) but don't seem to have any `content_range` property.

---

However, when I directly use the `blob_sas_url` i.e. `https://<cdn_hostname>/container_name/file.wav?se=<sas_token>` , I am able to download the file in my browser.

---

Additional point : I have also configured the caching rules to `cache all unique url`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with same code and got same error in my environment downloading blob through **`CDN`** end point:

[image]

After getting sas_url, the below code will only download  ***blob client Url*** (so kindly do not use below code)

`< https://<redacted_hostname>.blob.core.windows.net/container/blobname?sas`>

```py
blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url(blob_sas_url);
with open("download_file.wav", "wb") as current_blob:
    stream = blob_client.download_blob()
    current_blob.write(stream.readall())
```

I tried with **`request method`** after getting **`sas_url`** it downloaded file successfully.

**Code:**

```py
import datetime as dt
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import (
    BlobSasPermissions,
    BlobServiceClient,
    generate_blob_sas,
)
import requests

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    
storage_acct_name = "venkat123"
container_name = "test"
blob_name = "scores.json"

url = f"https://{storage_acct_name}.blob.core.windows.net"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(url, credential=credential)
udk = blob_service_client.get_user_delegation_key(
    key_start_time=dt.datetime.utcnow() - dt.timedelta(hours=1),
    key_expiry_time=dt.datetime.utcnow() + dt.timedelta(hours=1))

sas = generate_blob_sas(
    account_name=storage_acct_name,
    container_name=container_name,
    blob_name=blob_name,
    user_delegation_key=udk,
    permission=BlobSasPermissions(read=True,write=True,list=True),
    start = dt.datetime.utcnow() - dt.timedelta(minutes=15),
    expiry = dt.datetime.utcnow() + dt.timedelta(hours=2),
)

sas_url = (
    f'https://venkat3261.azureedge.net/'
    f'{container_name}/{blob_name}?{sas}'
)
print(sas_url)

r = requests.get(sas_url, allow_redirects=True)

open('scores.json', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Here, In my code I’m using azure-identity with user delegation key. You have to make sure that you have an access (authorization) and assign the role of storage-blob-contributor.

Go to portal -> your storage account -> Access Control (IAM) ->Add -> Add role assignments -> storage-blob-contributor or storage-blob-owner.

**Portal:**[image]

**Console:**
The above code is executed successfully and downloaded the file through azure cdn hostname with SAS_url.

[image]

**File:**

[image]

**For more reference**:

[Create a user delegation SAS - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas#assign-permissions-with-rbac).

Comment: I have updated the answer according to the query, kindly check.